# Repeat animation from left to right smoothly

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to animate 3 squares from the left to the right. The squares should reappear from the left while they are disappearing from the right. The idea is that the squares represent clouds, so the idea is clear.

This is what I currently got:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // contains the squares
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        startAnimating()
    }

    func startAnimating() {
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 10, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: {
            self.containerView.center.x += self.view.bounds.width

        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image: clouds]

The squares move from the left to the right. This is good. The problem is that once the animation is done the squares just reappear from where they started. It isn't a smooth continuous movement where the clouds move from the left to the right and slowly reappear from the left again. How do you achieve this? Should there be a second containerView? Or remove the containerView and animate individual clouds?

The answer Milan Nosáľ solved the problem. A note though:

> I placed containerView2 above containerView1 with the exact same
>   constraints (they overlap each other). Just make sure IB doesn't
>   include containerView2 as a subview of containerView1.

Comment: Everything clear in my answer?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Thank you, everything makes sense although I wouldn't know how to put the containerView2 to the left of the containerView1 since containerView uses the full width of the viewController

Comment: check it now.. sorry for the weird "hackarounds", but I don't usually use storyboards, and thus laying out the contents programmatically seems easy to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the simplest approach for you know is to use two exactly the same containers. You can use exactly the same code, and put the `containerView2` above `containerView` to make sure that cover one another.

And then simply use:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // contains the squares
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView2: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // this will transform the containerView2 to the left to appear as if it was exactly to the left of the containerView
        containerView2.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: -self.view.bounds.width, y: 0)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        startAnimating()
    }

    func startAnimating() {
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 10, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: {
            self.containerView.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
            self.containerView2.center.x += self.view.bounds.width

        }, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

The `containerView2` will represent the clouds coming back from the left.

Comment: This worked, now I have to finetune the animation but your answered solved the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like putting `containerView.center.x -= 200` right before starting the animation. This way it first appears from the left side.

Comment: This means that the clouds won't be visible until center.x > 0