# Animate UIStackView left to right continuously

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I am trying to animate some circle images so that they move from left to right. As soon as the circle starts to disappears from the right side of the screen it should reappear on the left in a continuous loop. I am using stackviews to accomplish this but having difficulty with having the images wrap around in their container.

I have taken some cues from this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282914/repeat-animation-from-left-to-right-smoothly) but i'm not getting the wrap around effect with the circles. What I have now the circles enter from left to right and at the end of the animation the mockedTemplateStackView circles are in the middle of the screen with half screen space to the left before the animation starts over.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        mockTemplateStackView.frame = templateStackView.frame
        mockTemplateStackView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: -self.view.bounds.width, y: 0)
        mockTemplateStackView.alignment = .fill
        mockTemplateStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        mockTemplateStackView.axis = .horizontal
        
        masterTemplateStackView.addArrangedSubview(mockTemplateStackView)
        
        for _ in 1...5 {
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: templateStackView.bounds.height * 0.5, height: templateStackView.bounds.height))
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "circle")
            imageView.backgroundColor = .white
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            templateStackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        }
        
        for _ in 1...5 {
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: mockTemplateStackView.bounds.height * 0.5, height: mockTemplateStackView.bounds.height))
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "circle")
            imageView.backgroundColor = .white
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            mockTemplateStackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)

       startAnimating()
    }

   func startAnimating() {
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 10, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: {
               self.templateStackView.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
        self.mockTemplateStackView.center.x += self.view.bounds.width

           }, completion: nil)
   }
```

StackView layout
[image: Stackview layout]

Animation starts:

[image: Animation starts]

Animation ends:

[image: Animation ends]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track...

We need two stack views, so we can show one entering as the other is leaving.

One approach is to give each stack view **TWO** Leading constraints. Each will have a leading constraint equal to the Leading anchor of the "container" view, and each will have a leading constraint equal to the Leading anchor of ***the other stack view***.

By changing the constraint priorities, we can make one stack "follow" the other stack. When the "leader" stack exits the view, we swap "leader" and "follower" and animate again.

Here's an example - I've tried to include plenty of comments to make it clear, but  please note it is **example code only** and should not be considered "production ready":

**SimpleCircleView** - outlined circle view

```
class SimpleCircleView: UIView {
    var c: UIColor = .white
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = c.cgColor
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.width * 0.5
    }
}
```

**MyStackView** - stack view subclass to manage constraints

```
class MyStackView: UIStackView {
    var leaderConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var followerConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
}
```

**CarouselView** - the view to do the animations

```
class CarouselView: UIView {
    
    public var speed: TimeInterval = 10
    public var stack1Color: UIColor = .blue
    public var stack2Color: UIColor = .blue

    private var stacks: [MyStackView] = []
    private var leaderStackID: Int = 0
    private var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        // create two stack views
        //  each with 5 circle views
        //  we can use different colors if we want to see the "lead/follow" change
        [stack1Color, stack2Color].forEach { c in
            let sv = MyStackView()
            sv.distribution = .fillEqually
            sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview(sv)
            for _ in 1...5 {
                let v = SimpleCircleView()
                v.c = c
                // 1:1 ratio
                v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.heightAnchor).isActive = true
                sv.addArrangedSubview(v)
            }
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
                sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            ])
            stacks.append(sv)
        }
        
        var c: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()

        // init "leader" constraints
        //  each stack will be constrained Leading to Leading of self
        c = stacks[0].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0)
        c.priority = .defaultLow
        c.isActive = true
        stacks[0].leaderConstraint = c

        c = stacks[1].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0)
        c.priority = .defaultLow
        c.isActive = true
        stacks[1].leaderConstraint = c
        
        // init "follower" constraints
        //  each stack will be constrained Leading to Leading of other stack
        c = stacks[0].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stacks[1].leadingAnchor)
        c.priority = .defaultLow
        c.isActive = true
        stacks[0].followerConstraint = c
        
        c = stacks[1].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stacks[0].leadingAnchor)
        c.priority = .defaultLow
        c.isActive = true
        stacks[1].followerConstraint = c
        
        // start with both stacks hidden
        stacks[0].isHidden = true
        stacks[1].isHidden = true

        // set to false if we want to see the circles
        //  as they travel outside the bounds of self
        //  (likely during dev only)
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
    
    public func toggleAnimation() -> Void {
        // start or toggle running/paused
        if animator == nil {
            startAnimation()
        } else {
            if animator.isRunning {
                animator.pauseAnimation()
            } else {
                animator.startAnimation()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func startAnimation() -> Void {
        
        // un-hide both stacks
        stacks[0].isHidden = false
        stacks[1].isHidden = false
        
        leaderStackID = 0
        
        let svLeader = stacks[leaderStackID]
        let svFollow = stacks[abs(leaderStackID - 1)]

        // set both follower constraint constants to width of self
        svLeader.followerConstraint.constant = -(bounds.width)
        svFollow.followerConstraint.constant = -(bounds.width)

        // start with the Leader ready to "come into view"
        svLeader.leaderConstraint.constant = -stacks[0].frame.width
        svLeader.leaderConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
        
        // tell the Follower to "follow the Leader"
        svFollow.followerConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.runAnimation()
        }
    }
    
    private func runAnimation() {
        
        let svLeader = stacks[leaderStackID]
        
        animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: speed, curve: .linear)
        
        animator.addAnimations {
            // animate the Leader to disappear off the right side of self
            svLeader.leaderConstraint.constant = self.bounds.width
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

        animator.addCompletion { _ in
            self.swapLeader()
        }
        
        animator.startAnimation()

    }
    
    private func swapLeader() -> Void {

        // current Leader has gone off the right side
        // current Follower has appeard at the left side
        // so swap the constraint priorities so
        //  Follower becomes Leader
        //    and
        //  Leader becomes Follower
        
        let svLeader = stacks[leaderStackID]
        let svFollow = stacks[abs(leaderStackID - 1)]
        
        svLeader.leaderConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
        svLeader.followerConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh

        svFollow.followerConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
        svFollow.leaderConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
        
        svFollow.leaderConstraint.constant = 0.0

        // this will toggle the leader ID between 0 and 1
        leaderStackID = abs(leaderStackID - 1)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.runAnimation()
        }
    }
    
}
```

**CarouselTestViewController** - example view controller

```
class CarouselTestViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let cView = CarouselView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        
        cView.backgroundColor = .white
        cView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(cView)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            cView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            cView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            cView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0),
        ])
        
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(t)

        // set animation duration if desired
        //cView.speed = 5
        // set circle colors if desired
        //cView.stack1Color = .red
        //cView.stack2Color = .green

        // add an instruction label
        let v = UILabel()
        v.text = "Tap anywhere to toggle animation."
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(v)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            v.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    @objc func didTap(_ g: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        cView.toggleAnimation()
    }
}
```

The output:

[image]